# How do I determine MaxDirectMemorySize on a running JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, bytebuffer

I have an application which uses DirectByteBuffers to store data, but I'd like to know what MaxDirectMemorySize is so I don't accidentally exceed it.

Without configuring this manually, how can I figure out, from within the program, what MaxDirectMemorySize is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yuu can get ALL JVM parameters with...

```
RuntimeMXBean RuntimemxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> args=RuntimemxBean.getInputArguments();

for(int i=0;i<args.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(args.get(i)); 
}
```

Comment: but if it's not set in a jvm argument, how do you find out what the value is?

Comment: I believe it always is. At least every time I've checked.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer only works if the option is explicitly specified on the command line. As of Java 6, you can access the option directly using the [`HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.html). The following Java 7 code can read it conveniently:

```
final HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean hsdiag = ManagementFactory
        .getPlatformMXBean(HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
if (hsdiag != null) {
    System.out.println(hsdiag.getVMOption("MaxDirectMemorySize"));
}
```

Note that this may return a value of zero, meaning to use the default setting, which is equal to `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`. For example, with Oracle JDK 7u71 64-bit on Windows 7, this returns 3,690,987,520.

Alternatively, if you're willing to resort to accessing the `sun.misc` package, it's available directly by calling [`sun.misc.VM.maxDirectMemory()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/b92353a01aa0/src/share/classes/sun/misc/VM.java#l165).

Comment: With the Oracle JDK 7u75 on my Windows 7 machine I get: 5,707,923,456 so I think this value is machine specific.